# Return a balanced search tree

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree

Given the root of binary search tree, return a balanced search tree with the same node values. The BST is balanced if it has an AVL-tree property

```
class Solution:
    def inOrderTraversal(self, root: TreeNode, arr: List[TreeNode]):
        if not root:
            return
        self.inOrderTraversal(root.left, arr)
        arr.append(root)
        self.inOrderTraversal(root.right, arr)
        
    def balanceBST(self, root: TreeNode) -> TreeNode:
        arr = []
        self.inOrderTraversal(root, arr)
        
        def constructBST(startIndex: int, endIndex: int, arr: List[TreeNode]):
            if startIndex > endIndex:
                return None
            n = endIndex - startIndex + 1
            # delegate median as the root
            mid = (startIndex + endIndex) // 2
            arr[mid].left = constructBST(startIndex, mid - 1, arr)
            arr[mid].right = constructBST(mid + 1, endIndex, arr)
            return arr[mid]
        
        return constructBST(0, len(arr) - 1, arr)
```

In this line, I get that we are splitting the array around the median into left and right subtrees and they will have the same height if they have the same number of nodes. But how do we know if the difference in their heights won't be more than 2 out of whack when one subtree has 1 more node than another?

```
            arr[mid].left = constructBST(startIndex, mid - 1, arr)
            arr[mid].right = constructBST(mid + 1, endIndex, arr)
```

Comment: How can 1 node create a height difference of 2?

Comment: Is this a binary tree, transfer to a list, and then rebuild balanced?

Comment: @Abhinav Mathur That's the intuition but I am looking for more constructive proof

Comment: You can add 1 more node to balanced BST to make a height difference of 2.
e.g) insert 11 and then insert 5. At this point it is balanced. Then if you insert 3, then it becomes unbalanced

Comment: The BST allows you to enumerate the nodes in sorted order. Then you should be able to fill a complete tree, which is implicitly AVL.

Comment: If you split an array at the median point, there can be at most a one element difference in the count of each part.

Comment: If you don't get an answer, this is probably a good question for https://cs.stackexchange.com/.